# Is using a class as a field in an annoation bad memory management?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, annotations

I have some design problems with an existing application. It can use annotations with a class field. As in the examples below. Are these fields going to cause to the class loader to stay in memory and create a leak?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface FieldDefinition {
  Class reportedType(); 
  //other fields also
}
```

Usage:

```
@FieldDefinition(reportedType=Foo.class)
String bar;
```

Comment: Which fields? `bar`, `reportedType` (which isn't a field, but a method)? What makes you think so? I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Well, the class is referenced in the annotation's field. It has a reference to the class loader. All of the classes within the class loader have a reference there. So I don't know the memory management used on annotations. Are they susceptible to a class loader leak?

Comment: No, the situation you are talking cannot and will not cause memory leaks.

Comment: sounds great :) but now to find a documented answer ...